# Python Recursion Error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to build a function that will take in a number and then use recursion to print out a Fibonacci sequence and end the sequence on the number. So if I have a sequence that starts on `0` and `1` if the users input is `4` it will return `0`,`1`,`1`,`2`,`3`. I am getting this `RecursionError`:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

This is my code:

```
num = input("Give me a number.")
def fib(n):
  n = int(n)
  if n == 0:
    return 1
  return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
print(fib(num))
```

Comment: What should `fib(-1)` return? If you're thinking "fib never gets called with a negative argument", consider what `return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)` does when `n` equals 1.

Comment: You are not accounting for the possibilty that `fib(n - 2)` will give you an n of `-1` when `n` is 1.

Comment: If you do input like `1`, I think you'll see the problem. Is `fib(1 - 2)` ever going to terminate?

Comment: Spoiler alert: if you are patient enough, you are going to get a `RecursionError` for large values of `n` even if you fix the current issue. This is not a good way to compute arbitrary Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Save recursion for recursive data structures; for everything thing else, use loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Two problems

There are two problems with your code:

- There is an infinite loop, which generates the `RecursionError` exception
- It is impossible to retrieve all terms of the sequence (you said you want to print all the sequence, not only the last term)

### The infinite loop

Try the code below. I just added `n==1` as another stop condition.

```py
def fib(n):
    n = int(n)
    if n == 0 or n == 1:  # Changed here
        return 1
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

num = input("Give me a number: ")

print(fib(num))
```

The case `f(1)=1` is required by definition (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)).
Or just debugging your code, you will realize that the loop will never end for `fib(1)` because it returns:
`f(1-1) + f(1-2)` >>> `f(0) + f(-1)` >>> `1 + infinite loop`.

### Printing all terms

You could try to use lists in your recursive code, which is tricky to do or perhaps change to a version with loops.

With loops:

```py
# A version using a while loop
# This code returns the list of terms
def fib(n):

    n=int(n)
    terms = []

    i=0
    while i<=n:
        if i==0 or i==1:
            terms.append(1)
        else:
            terms.append(terms[-2]+terms[-1])
        i+=1

    return terms
```

Recursive:

```py
Working on it
```

**Try all these examples [here](https://onlinegdb.com/rJBk6uW88)**.

Answer (score 1):

The second call to `fib` is the problem. You pass the base case (exit condition) and continue to recurse without end. This generates the recursion error.

```
# to fix, replace "if n == 0:" with:

if n == 0 or n == 1:
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because you are using the wrong rule for Fibonacci... The Rule says that the initial number is 1 and 2 but you wrote your code starting in 0. Change your code:

```
num = input("Give me a number.")
def fib(num):
    n = int(num)
    if n == 1 or n == 2: # Changed here
        return 1
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

print(fib(num))
```